# Getting odd result from chown in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, chown

The script below is the beginning of my attempt to automate some of my website creation on a server running nginx. I plan on adding more but I'm no bash expert so I'm trying to learn. The problem is in line 26 where it should chown the htdocs folder as *user* (first part of domain name called on command line) and *group* = www-data. It all works but the user always ends up being literally "domain" - not the domain itself but the word "domain." This variable comes through fine in the rest of the script and I can echo it out at the end and it is correct there as well. I must be missing something simple but it's driving me crazy at this point. Anyone have a take on this? FYI, the script is called with the full domain after on the command line, mk_home.sh example.com. Thanks.

**Update:** when tried on another server, this behavior was not repeated. I'm still not sure what caused it originally.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script mk_home.sh to create user, home and set permissions for hosting.

line=$1
MAIN=${line%.*}
EXT=${line#*.}

# create random password
PASSWD="$(openssl rand -base64 12)"
echo $MAIN
echo $PASSWD

# start creation of home
mkdir /srv/www/$1
chmod go-w /srv/www/$1
mkdir /srv/www/$1/htdocs

# quietly add a user without password
adduser --quiet --disabled-password -shell /bin/nologin --gecos "$1" $MAIN

# set password
echo "$MAIN:$PASSWD" | chpasswd

# finish permissions on home
chown $MAIN:www-data /srv/www/$1/htdocs
chmod ug+rwX /srv/www/$1/htdocs

# add default home to user
usermod -d /srv/www/$1/htdocs $MAIN
```

Comment: And, when you echo `$MAIN`, what do you see? In addition, I'd be using absolute permissions like `766` rather than `go-w`, to ensure they're set _exactly_ to what you need.

Comment: `domain` is a username on your system, ¿no? Have you checked that the newly created usernames have unique uids? (I don't know why they wouldn't, but if a uid has more than one name attached to it, `ls -l` may not show you the one you expect.)

Comment: By the way, I think `adduser` will create a default user directory unless you ask it not to (with `--no-create-home`). Although that is dependent on your adduser configuration file.

Comment: When I echo $MAIN I get what it should be, the first part of the domain given, such as "example" in example.com. And no, that's not a user on that system. I've just tried it on another server and it worked, almost. The user part is now correct, though I need to modify adduser so that it assigns the new user to the group www-data. Right now it creates a group by the same name. I have no idea what the deal was on the other server. The assigned UIDs are unique and sequential. Thanks for the prompt, good ideas.

Comment: paxdiablo, the permissions are from this reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes. I found that explanation after quite a bit of research on how to make SFTP access work for individual users. To be honest, I haven't looked into it after that as I was so glad to get it working. If the same can be accomplished with absolute permissions, and you know what they would be, I would be happy to try it.  Thanks. rici, I also added the no-create-home and it seems to work.

Comment: @DavidRahrer: If you're getting the incorrect `user:group` information from `ls -l`, and it says that the username is `domain`, then either there *is* a username `domain` or your `nsswitch.conf` file is messed up. I'd try the following two things first: (1) verify the ownership information numerically using `ls -n`. (2) Check what name that uid prints with `getent passwd uuu` (where `uuu` is the number printed by `ls -n`. (3) If getent shows you `domain`, check the passwd entry for domain, `getent passwd domain`. If you find inconsistencies, look at `/etc/nsswitch.conf` for errors.

Comment: @DavidRahrer: Also, as you probably know, you can use the `--gid ID` or `--in-group NAME` options to `adduser` in order to set the group id for the new user.

Comment: @rici: I grew frustrated with the issue and reformatted the VPS. The fantom domain user has gone. I assume it was due to the earlier testing but there was no visible user named domain, though there might have been at one time if I used "domain.com" as a test for the script and forgot it. I've saved your information should it reoccur. I also added the --gid ID switch and that works fine - thank you. It all seems to be working now, but I'm not experienced with stack enough to know what I should do in this situation.

Comment: @DavidRahrer: Your question is really more about system administration than about programming, and I'd suggest you think about asking similar questions on http://serverfault.com/ . But there is no precise boundary, and it might not have been obvious that the problem had more to do with server configuration than bugs in your script. Anyway, I marked the question as "no longer reproducible", and I suppose it will eventually get closed; you don't really need to do anything. Glad you got things worked out.